Where to put code that was in module initialization with Angular standalone
When using NgModules, it it possible to run code when that module is initialized, including it in the constructor. For example, here's how the ng-select component suggets it should be configured: https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select?tab=readme-ov-file#step-4-optional-configuration.
How can something similar be done in an application that is standalone and does not use NgModules?
Specifically, I'd like to only execute the code when a part of the application is lazy-loaded (using something like loadChildren: () => import(...).then(m => m.MyModule) in the Router configuration). When using modules, the constructor for the module will only be run when that route is loaded.
But with a module-less application, loadChildren only lazily loads a list of Routes, not a module, so there's no way to run code when those routes are being initialized.
If it weren't for the lazy loading requirment, an AppInitializer could be used, but that will cause the code to always be run when the app is started.
I'm aware that I can still use NgModules, and that might as well be a situation where it makes sense to do so, but I wonder if there is another solution.

In the lazy loaded component that you want this logic to execute, just add this code block to the constructor, it is executed during the first usage of the component, even if it called again, it does not matter, since it's just static properties being assigned.
Notice we are using importProvidersFrom(NgSelectModule) this code makes the service available at the component level and all components which are children of this component will have access to the same service.
import { NgSelectModule } from '@ng-select/ng-select';
...

...
@Component({
  ...
  standalone: true,
  imports: [NgSelectModule],
  provider: [importProvidersFrom(NgSelectModule)], // <- notice!
  ...
})
export class ComponentUsingNgSelect {
   constructor(private config: NgSelectConfig) {
      this.config.notFoundText = 'Custom not found';
      this.config.appendTo = 'body';
      // set the bindValue to global config when you use the same 
      // bindValue in most of the place. 
      // You can also override bindValue for the specified template 
      // by defining `bindValue` as property
      // Eg : <ng-select bindValue="some-new-value"></ng-select>
      this.config.bindValue = 'value';
   }
}

Now all the children of ComponentUsingNgSelect will share the same configuration. Due to this component being the parent of the dependency injection tree.
You can either use the NgSelectModule or NgSelectComponent and other imports directly on the child standalone components, but there should be only one importProvidersFrom(NgSelectModule), since we are sharing that service configuration defaults among many components.
Standalone: Import NgSelectComponent and other necessary directives directly:
import { NgLabelTemplateDirective, NgOptionTemplateDirective, NgSelectComponent } from '@ng-select/ng-select';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'example',
  standalone: true,
  template: './example.component.html',
  styleUrl: './example.component.scss',
  imports: [
    NgLabelTemplateDirective,
    NgOptionTemplateDirective,
    NgSelectComponent,
  ],
})
export class ExampleComponent {}

NgModule: Import the NgSelectModule and angular FormsModule module:
import { NgSelectModule } from '@ng-select/ng-select';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [NgSelectModule, FormsModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}


I've edited the question to make it clearer that I'd like to run the code when lazily loading a set of routes. Your solution unfortunately does not apply to my exact situation.
